# How to interpret results and plot posterior using a Python PyJAGS model?

Tags: python

Firstly, I am very new to python.. so excuse any dumb mistakes I might be making.

But Im using PyJAGS to analyse sea level data provided here:
[sea level data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andrewcparnell/tsme_course/master/data/church_and_white_global_tide_gauge.csv)

The head (first 5 rows) of the data looks like this:
[image: sea level 5 rows]

In my code I'm setting x = year_AD and y = sea_level_m and N = 130 (no. of rows in the data).

The JAGS model I'm using is the one provided in the PyJAGS documentation for linear regression:

```
code = '''
model {
    for (i in 1:N) {
        y[i] ~ dnorm(alpha + beta * x[i], tau)
    }
    # Priors
    alpha ~ dunif(0, 1e-2)
    beta ~ dnorm(0, 1e-2)
    tau <- 1 / sigma^2
    sigma ~ dunif(0, 10)
}
'''
```

I am then calling the PyJAGS model like so:

```
model = pyjags.Model(code, data=dict(x = x, y = y, N = N), chains = 4) 

# Number of iterations to remove at start and amount of thinning
model.sample(200, vars=[], thin = 2)

# Choose the parameters to watch and iterations:
samples = model.sample(1000, vars=['alpha', 'beta', 'sigma'])
```

However, the issue I'm having is the results seem to be off, compared to when running the same model in R (using R2jags). For instance, the mean of alpha & beta from the PyJAGS model are:

> alpha_mean = 0.004634, beta_mean = -0.000038

And in R:

> alpha_mean = -3.062718, beta_mean = 0.001538208

And when plotting the posterior mean things are going awry... Here's the plot in python and the code used:

```
# Creating a plot:
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.ylabel('sea_level_m')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.plot(x, alpha_mean + beta_mean * x, c = "blue")
```

[image: Python plot]

However, when running the same code in R I get this (correct) plot:
[image: R plot]

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?